# oAuth2 authentication via different callbakUrl

Tags: oauth-2.0

Currently my PHP website is connecting to certain API which uses a fixed bearer token authentication. This now is going to change to oAuth2 and having some struggle to understand the concept.

So basically I am testing it via postman and all works fine by using
https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback as the callbarkURL and using Microsoft as authentication provider.
I get my token from the first call and then I can use it in other calls until it expires.

The problem is that once I go to my PHP website I implement the same but when the authentication is succesful, it redirects me to Postman (I used same URL as above...).
Then I change it to something else like its own URL or localhost and then the Microsoft authentication stops me:

> The redirect URI 'https://localhost' specified in the request does not
> match the redirect URIs configured for the application...

Does that mean that for every different URL that uses these APIs, then I need to have that registered as applicationId/callbakURL in Azure?

Is there any way to bypass this? Or is that the "magic" of this authentication type?

EDIT: API provider mentioned that i should use grant type "Authorization code". Not sure if that is adjustable though...